# How to create hundreds of radiobuttons using For loop?

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, radio-button

I am trying to create many radiobuttons using for loop on a window form. The problem that I am facing is to generate a variable name for each individual radiobutton. Originally, I plan to add different numbers like 0001 , 0002 to each radiobutton. However, I cannot do it because the variable name is not string. Any suggestion?

Comment: You're going to run into serious performance problems with "hundreds" of controls on a form. And your users will pitch a serious fit, because there's nothing at all "usable" about that interface. But this is easy to do, in just the way that you describe. What do you mean "the variable name is not string"? Yes, it is. Look for the `Name` property of the radio button control.

Comment: @CodyGray I plan to put those buttons into a panel with scrollbar.

Comment: @CodyGray I know there is name field like this->radioButton1->Name = L"radioButton1"; . L"radioButton1" is the string, but the radioButton1 in (this->radioButton1->Name) is not string. How I should handle that?

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter. You can reuse the same variable name to create all of the objects in a loop. If you need to retain the ability to access them individually through code, you can place them into an array (something like a `List<RadioButton>`) as you iterate through the loop. (I'd just write some sample code and post an answer, but I'm telling myself that it's easier to write comments on an iPhone... Maybe if I remember later.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array:

```
RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    rb[i] = new RadioButton();
    rb[i].Location = new Point(0, i * 20);
    rb[i].Text = "Your text here";
    groupBox1.Controls.Add(rb[i]);
    //etc.
}
```

This is in C#, as I don't know VC++, but maybe it can help you.

Comment: One thing that I don't understand is how to add each of the radiobutton on a groupbox? I am confused that there should have statement like  "this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->radioButton4);" Isn't it? You use the for-loop to create, but they are not really on something to display. Am I right? I am sorry that I am very new to VC++.

Comment: @Marco I added that to my answer. And also corrected a mistake in the original answer where I didn't create the RadioButtons themselves. Again, this is in C#.

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```
        var rb = new List<RadioButton>();
        bool Satisfied = false; int location =0;

        while (!Satisfied)
        {
            rb.Add(new RadioButton() { Location = new Point(0, location * 20), Text = location.ToString() });
            location++;
            Satisfied = rb.Count > 100 ? true : false;
        }


        foreach ( object r in rb)
        {
            this.Controls.Add((RadioButton)r);
        }
```